# is there any difference between static cast to rvalue reference and std::move

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, static-cast, stdmove

The description for static cast says

> If new_type is an rvalue reference type, static_cast converts the value of expression to xvalue. This type of static_cast is used to implement move semantics in std::move.(since C++11)

Does this confirm that the following are equivalent ?

(A)

```
X x1;
X x2 = static_cast<X&&>(x1);
```

(B)

```
X x1;
X x2 = std::move(x1);
```

Comment: They are equivalent but move is less error prone.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes there is a very important difference: `std::move` documents what you want to do. In addition the cast is prone to writing errors like a forgotten `&` or wrong type `X`.

As it can be seen, `std::move` is even less to type.

Comment: I use "`static_cast<X&&>`" only when `move` is *not* `constexpr` and I need that attribute.

Answer (score 4):

In C++11, **`T&&`** is an rvalue reference. They behave like lvalue references from C++ 98/03. Their goal - to be a candidate for moving. In C++98 this construct can appear in reference collapsing.

**`std::move`** - turn expression into an rvalue. It could have been called *rvalue_cast*, but wasn't.

Explicit cast to type `T&&` is possible in principle. The official standard costs some money, but in the [ISO/IEC 14882:2011](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) draft there's this:

> 5.2.9 Static cast
>
> 8)
>
> The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) conversions are applied to the operand....

From a practical point of view, it is more convenient to use `std::move`.

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>

class A
{
public:
A () {printf ("A ()" "\n");}
A (const A &) {printf ("A (&)" "\n");}
A (A &&) {printf ("A (&&)" "\n");}
A (const A &&) {printf ("A (const &&)" "\n");}
~ A () {printf ("~ A ()" "\n");}
};


int main ()
{
const A obj;
A obj2 (std::move (obj)); // 1-st approach
A obj3 (static_cast <const A&&> (obj));  // 2-nd approach
}
```

For me, the first approach is:

- more convenient (should you perform `static_cast` to **`const A&&`**, or to **`A&&`** ?)
- more explicitly (I can use search in text editor to find `std::move` in the project)
- less error-prone.

Comment: no need for an `rvalue_cast` _keyword_. Just do `template<typename T> template<typename T>
constexpr auto rvalue_cast(T&& t) { return std::move(t); };` if you really want to use that name.

Answer (score 2):

They are not strictly equivalent. `std::move()`'s implementation relies on `static_cast`:

```
template<typename _Tp>
constexpr typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&
move(_Tp&& __t) noexcept
{ return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&>(__t); }
```

They differ in the sense that `std::move()` has `remove_reference` to deal with [reference collapse](https://rafaeljin.gitlab.io/2020/04/05/move-semantics/#reference-collapse-and-universal-reference). An example where (A) and (B) are not strictly equivalent:

```
// Set up different behavior for lvalue and rvalue.
class T {};
void func(T&& t) { std::cout << "rvalue captured.\n"; }
void func(T& t) { std::cout << "lvalue captured.\n"; }
// Example:
Using X = T&;
X x1;
X x2 = static_cast<X&&>(x1); // (A) "lvalue captured."
X x3 = std::move(x1);        // (B) "rvalue captured."
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `static_cast<A &&>(a)` when a is an rvalue, but you shouldn't use `std::move(a)`.
When you use `A && a = std::move(A())`, you get a dangling reference.

The basic idea is that the lifetime of a temporary cannot be further extended by "passing it on": a second reference, initialized from the reference to which the temporary was bound, does not affect its lifetime.

`std::move`'s implementation is somewhat like

```
template <typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) move(T && __t) noexcept  // when used in std::move(A()),
                                                  // the lifetime of the temporary object is extended by __t
{
    return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type &&>(__t);  // a xvalue returned, no lifetime extension
}

auto && a = std::move(A());  // the anonymous object wiil be destructed right after this line
```

Comment: I don't see how you get dangling references in your second example.  Also, what's wrong with `std::move(a)` when `a` is an rvalue?  The result of `std::move((const int &)a)` is just `const int &&`, which is what you want.

Comment: @SirGuy A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call exists until the end of the full expression containing that function call: if the function returns a reference, which outlives the full expression, it becomes a dangling reference. `move` takes a rvalue reference to the to-be-casted prvalue expression as an argument.

Comment: `A&& a = std::move(A());` would be a dangling reference (as would the static_cast version of the same)... `A a` is not a reference, therefore not a dangling one

Comment: Your "corrected typo" now means you aren't answering the question;  both `std::move` and `static_cast<A&&>` generate a dangling reference there., but the question is about whether those two things differ.  Also you say in your comment that `static_cast<A &&>(A())` is identical to a single `A()`", however `std::move(A())` is also identical to the cast;  and neither is exactly identical to `A()` , since they are xvalues and not prvalues (with associated lifetime extension problem that you already mentioned)

Comment: don't we have a new rule that extends temporaries life bound to rval references ? it was true for const ref already.

Comment: @v.oddou just bound directly.