# Why create std::move and not use static_cast

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I don't understand the reason why `std::move()` had to be created. Couldn't everything just be `static_cast<T&&>()` instead? The only reason that I find why `std::move()` might have been created is just to make code easier to read. So, instead of seeing `static_cast`, programmers could see `std::move()` and understand what it is doing. Other than that, I see no purpose. Can someone help me understand why they created `std::move()`?.

Comment: *programmers could see std::move and understand what it is doing* Is that not a good enough reason? Readability is extremely important.

Comment: Related or duplicate Q/A's: [C++11 move(x) actually means static_cast<X&&>(x)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20533960/5023438), [is there any difference between static cast to rvalue reference and std::move](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17142167/5023438), [std::move() is just casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47374251/5023438)

Comment: It's actually a little more than `static_cast<T&&>` - it's `static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t)` - and with that, `std::move(t)` is beginning to look pretty nice.

Comment: Just to complicate matters, be careful not to confuse [`std::move()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) in `<utility>` with [`std::move()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) in `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's mostly about readability.

In addition to clearly expressing the intent, `std::move` doesn't require you to manually write the type.

Comment: The name `std::move` is misleading tho. `as_rvalue` would be better imho..

Answer (score 2):

A quick googling on the proposal [n1377](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm)

> The static_cast<A&&> syntax is admittedly ugly. This is not
> necessarily a bad thing as you want to clearly call out when you are
> doing something as dangerous (and useful!) as moving from an lvalue.
> But the cast can become so ugly as to be unreadable when the type A is
> a long complicated identifier.